# ios Container View change View

Tags: ios, swift

I have a containerView added to a View Controller.  I am hoping to on swipe of the containerView change the view in the container.  However when I use the following in my swipe action function it adds the view to the whole page not just changing the view inside the container.

```
 class SwipeDateViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var swipeContainer: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    @IBAction func swipeLeftHandler(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
        let viewController = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "swipeViewControllerStoryboard") as! SwipeViewController
        self.swipeContainer.addSubview(viewController.view)
    }
}
```

How do I just change the view in the container and not update the whole screen?

Comment: Not 100% sure what you are trying to do here but it kind of seems like you are trying to page between view controllers. If so then you should look at UIPageViewController.

If not then you should also make sure to add the view controller as a child. addChildViewController(viewController). You could also try setting swipeContainer.clipsToBounds = true

Comment: You may also want to add constraints between swipeContainer and the viewController.view

Answer (score 1):

I think maybe you could add modify function in your custom vc.
Then just run function of it.

For example:

```
var customVC:EmbeddedViewController?

func addView() {
    let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "EmbeddedViewController") as! EmbeddedViewController
    self.addChild(vc)
    vc.view.bounds = CGRect.init(x: 20, y: 40, width: 50, height: 60)
    self.view.addSubview(vc.view)
    vc.didMove(toParent: self)
    customVC = vc
}


@IBAction func actionAddView(_ sender: Any) {
  customVC?.changeColor(color: UIColor.black)
}
```

EmbeddedViewController

```
class EmbeddedViewController: UIViewController {
  public func changeColor(color:UIColor) {
      self.view.backgroundColor = color
  }
}
```